# premisson to working correctly laravel

Tags: php, linux, apache, web, laravel-4

I created a project with Laravel 4 but when I go to the folder localhost /my_project/public get some errors related to the permissions. I solved it setting to 777  all the permissions of the folder and files contained in my_project. Is there a way to solve this thing is not to make 777?

Answer (score 0):

What's happen when you set 755 permission to my_project directory? Try to change permissions and check it. Your directory should be able to read all files in public directory.

Answer (score 0):

I set my ownership to be owned by `www-data`:

```
chown -R auser:www-data /path/to/laravel/root
```

I also make all my subfolders and files `read` and `write` by group:

```
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/laravel/root
```

I also make my folders have a sticky bit so if you add a new file, it inherits:

```
chmod -R g+s /path/to/laravel/root
```

This has always worked for me.  Perhaps Linux experts might have better ideas but this is what I use.

Comment: This may be fine for a development setup, but never for production as it grants unnecesary privileges to files and folders. Webserver only need write access to "app/storage", if you want uploads to the document root then you can grant access to the "public" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Laravel's documentation about installation located at http://laravel.com/docs/installation. Under no circumstances you should run laravel on production with full permissions to the whole world. You must also remember that your "application" will be executed from the public directory so there is NO reason to allow read/write/execute for the whole world to the whole project directory unless you don't care about security at all.

Anyway, extracted from Laravel's documentation from the permissions section:

> "Laravel may require one set of permissions to be configured: folders
>   within app/storage require write access by the web server."

This whould make your project run smooth.

Comment: It is more complicated than setting the permission of storage directories. Files in there (e.g. templates, cache, logs) will need to be written by both the web user and the installation user. On Linux a `sticky bit` may help to copy permissions from the directories to new files as they are created.